# How to make two Python Tornado websocket channels available at different URLs

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have two queues that should be subscribed to separately when opening a websocket connection to either endpoint. One should be ws://127.0.0.1:8000/channel_one and the other is ws://127.0.0.1:8000/channel_two.

How do I implement this URL structure in Python Tornado and make it so there are two endpoints in the same program?

Comment: The question is unclear. A tornado server can have any number of endpoints as you like. Do you want two endpoints for a single `WebsocketHandler`?

Comment: @xyres yes two endpoints. As in two handler classes that serve two types of data. Then you access each using ws://localhost:8000/channel_one and ws://localhost:8000/channel_two. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible; as shown in the answer below by *friedcell*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting the sample hello world app:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

class HandlerOne(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    pass

class HandlerTwo(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    pass

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/channel_one", HandlerOne),
        (r"/channel_two", HandlerTwo),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```